# Want to open Drawer with only a button instead of scrolling from sides in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a IconButton to open endDrawer , its working fine,

but how to prevent opening drawer while sliding from sides...

I mean to open Drawer only with icon button

```
 Builder(
          builder: (context){
            return  IconButton(onPressed: (){
              Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
            },icon: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.blue.shade700,),);
          },
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to write one line in your scaffold

```
Scaffold(
   drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
   drawer: ...
)
```